# c3.js remove empty spaces between timeseries with non consecutive days

Tags: c3.js

I made a bar graph with c3.js and I need to add non consecutive days to the graph

The problem is that the graph adds empty days

http://c3js.org/samples/timeseries.html

I used this code, it is possible to copy and paste code in page and see live result

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        type: 'bar',
        columns: [
            ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-07', '2013-01-09', '2013-01-10', '2013-01-11'],
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 250, 250, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350, 250, 250, 250]
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a category axis instead of a timeseries axis. Check the example:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    x: 'x',
    type: 'bar',
    columns: [
        ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05', '2013-01-07', '2013-01-09', '2013-01-10', '2013-01-11'],
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 250, 250, 250],
        ['data2', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350, 250, 250, 250]
    ],

},
axis: {
    x: {
        type: 'category',
        tick: {
       centered: true
   }
    }
}});
```

Comment: this is kind of work around, the advantage of date is that i can easily change how to display them, if is not possible with timeseries I will accept as an answer

Comment: Following the official documentation there is no prop to set that.